# Looping with row/child structures

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm starting to face this issue more and more often and am wondering if there is a simple solution to this. Kinda stuck trying to loop through a set of data into a row/child kind of structure.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<div class="row">
  <div>Data 1</div>
  <div>Data 2</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>Data 3</div>
  ...
```

What I ended doing most of the time is to just now house my data loops into a row, etc. But it prevented me from displaying my data in a more customised way... Is there a better way?

```
<div v-for="item in items">
   <div class="row">
    <div>{{ item.message }}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Like after 3 item.messages, a new row will spawn, etc?

Comment: Hi @Bert, like for eg. just a single list of maybe 10 todos. But I want every 3 todos to be housed in a row div. So the result would be 4 rows. First 3 rows with 3 data inside, and a last row with one data inputted. With the normal v-for loop, I either end up with 10 rows with one data in each, or 1 row with 10 data in them. I'm wondering how I can break up the looping so that it can follow the 1 row 3 data structure.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically how I would handle this is use a computed value to group the data in the manner I wanted, and then iterate over the grouped data.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    todos: [
      {id: 1, text: "learn Vue"},
      {id: 2, text: "learn Vuex"},
      {id: 3, text: "learn Vue Router"},
      {id: 4, text: "learn javascript"},
      {id: 5, text: "wash dishes"},
      {id: 6, text: "go to gym"},
      {id: 7, text: "go out with Sally"},
    ],
    todosPerRow: 3
  },
  computed:{
    grouped(){
      return this.todos.reduce((acc, val, ndx) => {
        let key = Math.floor(ndx / this.todosPerRow)
        if (acc[key]) acc[key].push(val)
        else acc[key] = [val]
        return acc
      }, {})
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.7/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="group in grouped">
    <div class="row">
      <div v-for="todo in group">{{todo.text}}</div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Here I just wrote a quick and dirty grouping function. Libraries like lodash also implement a `groupBy` method you could use instead.

Comment: Nice! I shall go try it out and also check out lodash. Thanks~~~